# EF and OData entity relationships - need some basic help bad

Tags: entity-framework, odata

I have what I think is a very basic problem. Created an OData web server to serve up Customers and Orders. Each order has a relationship to a Customer. Code snippet is:

```
public class Customer
{
   int Id {get;set;}
...
}
public class Order
{
   int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual Customer customer {get;set;}
...
}
```

When the web service creates the db and tables, it all looks good. If I add a Order object (in the orders controller) with the customer object set correctly, the generated Customer_Id foreign key field gets filled in. My problems are:

1. On the client, when I add an order to the OData container, it does not serialize the customer object so the controller gets a null value. When I set the customer object in the controller, EF seems to handle the process fine putting in the right Id for that customer.

Am wondering if I need a .AddLink call on the client app. If so, not sure what to add as all my attempts throw exceptions.

container.AddLink(order.Customer,"Customer",order); (throws exception that order does not have a settable property)

2. When I try and retrieve an order object, the customer object is always null. I have disabled LazyLoading and even have a .Include(o=>o.Customer) in the orders controller get handler.

Think I am missing something pretty basic, just not getting what I need to do to make this work. I do have an embedded complex type that is working as expected, just can't get the entity relationships to flow in the client.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you using an $expand clause in the HTTP request?

Comment: No. Thanks for the question, searched and got this link from a quick search. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client

Comment: Will have to try it out, but sounds like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for. Is there something similar to invoke when adding an object with entity relationships?